# update the value of a variable which is defined using #define in c

Tags: c

In C language 
if I define a value using #define
eg:

```
#define STATE 1
```

Can I update the value of `STATE` further in the program?
If it is possible, tell me how?

Comment: That's not a variable. You should read about how the C preprocessor works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor is a text-substitution system.  In other words, when you use the symbol `STATE` elsewhere in your program it's replaced by its definition, (`1`).

For example, if you write:

```
printf("%d\n", STATE);
```

The preprocessor replaces `STATE` with `1` and what the compiler actually "sees" is:

```
printf("%d\n", 1);
```

If you were to try to update `STATE` within C code you'd get errors about assigning to an r-value.

If you want to re-define state within the preprocessor, you could do:

```
#define STATE 1
#undef STATE
#define STATE 2
```

Comment: Such code is very dangerous and considered bad practice if used outside few lines of code. It is also not clear what OP wants without more information.